# Does Google Analytics iOS requires AdSupport to use IDFA

Tags: ios, google-analytics, appstore-approval, idfa, demographics

My iOS app (iOS 9+) uses Google Analytics(3.14) to collect Demographic data. According to Google's instructions, IDFA is required for this. Does GA needs iAd and AdSupport frameworks to use IDFA?

My app doesn't show any ads. Will it be rejected by app store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2):

Only AdSupport framework is required.
Your app will not be rejected, if during submission in the iTunesConnect you will specify a correct reason for using IDFA (they have a drop-down to select from)